# Find the path of notepad.exe and mspaint.exe

Tags: winapi, search, filesystems, filepath

What is the best way to find out where notepad.exe and mspaint.exe are that will work across various versions of Windows?

Should I get the Windows directory via [`SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_WINDOWS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, dir)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx), and then traverse through all the subdirectories to look for the two files?

(Assume that I am not interested in anything outside the Windows folder.)

Comment: Whatever solution you decide on, be prepared to *not* find them at all. I have deleted either or both on some systems (why should I keep notepad.exe around when I have notepad++)

Comment: @Stephen: What's the point in deleting such lightweight little things which won't really release any resources but just introduce the risk of breaking some programs?

Answer (score 41):

This works on every Windows box I've got access to (XP+).

```
c:\> for %i in (cmd.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

c:\> for %i in (python.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i
C:\Python25\python.exe
```

The great thing is, you don't *have* to use the actual `%PATH%`, you can substitute your own search path by using a different environment variable.

Comment: It wouldn't on many localized versions of Windows as the executable might be named differently.

Comment: Then you substitute the localized name. This will be a problem with any solution unless you think there's a WIN_NOTEPAD_REALNAME constant somewhere in the Win32 API.

Comment: notepad.exe is still notepad.exe and cmd.exe is still cmd.exe in all the language versions of Windows (98,XP,Vista) I've seen (about 20). Folders may be named differently, but executables, libraries, and other important stuff are not translated - at least not the filenames.

Comment: I don't think this works when the filename is in multiple paths, 'cos it doesn't seem to display all the paths.. for example, tail.exe i've got in a windows resource kit, and as part of gnuwin32  and in cygwin\bin so 3 places, but it only displays one.

Comment: @barlop, it mirrors what Windows will do when you type in `tail.exe` - that will only run the first copy (in terms of your path), not all three.

Comment: what is the significance of `.` in `@echo.` ?

Comment: @MiserableVariable, under (old) DOS from memory, if you typed `echo     hello` (with many spaces between the words, those spaces were _ignored_ and you just got "hello". If you used the dot variant, it would output the spaces between the dot and the word as well. XP (at least) seems to have change that so that the _first_ space (or dot) is ignored, the others are preserved. Force of habit on the part of an aging IT guy :-) Unnecessary here so I'll get rid of it.

Comment: Could someone explain how this works? I don't understand the meaning of "%~$PATH:i"

Answer (score 19):

If you have the Microsoft Platform SDK installed ([the February 2003 version](http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/psdk-full.htm) is the last one that works with Microsoft VC6), you can grab the `where.exe` program (it's 38K, only 18K if you gzip it) and run

```
where notepad.exe
```

help from the `where` command:

```
WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern...

Description:
    Displays the location of files that match the search pattern.
    By default, the search is done along the current directory and
    in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.

Parameter List:
    /R       Recursively searches and displays the files that match the
             given pattern starting from the specified directory.

    /Q       Returns only the exit code, without displaying the list
             of matched files. (quite mode)

    /F       Displays the matched filename in double quotes.

    /T       Displays the file size, last modified date and time for all
             matched files.

    pattern  Specifies the search pattern for the files to match.
             Wildcards * and ? can be used in the pattern. The
             "$env:pattern" and "path:pattern" formats can also be
             specified, where "env" is an environment variable and
             the search is done in the specified paths of the "env"
             environment variable. These formats should not be used
             with /R. The search is also done by appending the
             extensions of the PATHEXT variable to the pattern.

     /?      Displays this help message.

  NOTE: The tool returns an error level of 0 if the search is
        successful, of 1 if the search is unsuccessful and
        of 2 for failures or errors.

Examples:
    WHERE /?
    WHERE myfilename1 myfile????.*
    WHERE $windir:*.*
    WHERE /R c:\windows *.exe *.dll *.bat
    WHERE /Q ??.???
    WHERE "c:\windows;c:\windows\system32:*.dll"
    WHERE /F /T *.dll
```

Comment: "where" available in Windows 7 by default and maybe in Vista

Answer (score 3):

Check if the key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe is the same on localized versions. Maybe the key name is same and the value for edit/open points to the localized exe.
Example:

English:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell\edit\command
%SystemRoot%\system32**NOTEPAD.EXE** %1

Dutch:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell\edit\command
%SystemRoot%\system32**kladblok.exe** %1

If thats the case, then its just about to check the registry for that key (same goes for the mspaint).

Comment: Sounds like a viable way of doing this, yes. Provided that the assumption holds. (Can't check myself, as I'm not on a non-English localized Windows and I don't have registry editing permissions here...)

Comment: Anyone else that has possibility to check?

Comment: at least in the german version the key is the same, however notepad.exe still is called notepad.exe

Answer (score 3):

Type:

```
%windir%\system32\notepad.exe
```

in the path bar thingy.

Or

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

and find `notepad.exe`. ***C*** is the hard drive where your OS is located.

Answer (score 2):

I think to start off small you should get the `windir` environment variable and look in the subfolders `%windir%\system32\` for `mspaint` and `notepad`.
Most likely they will be there.

However if that fails, well then resort to a more brute force search.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would just execute them. They are on the system path in every version of Windows.

You can use [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265(VS.85).aspx). The environment variable you want to expand is `WINDIR`.

In the past you could have used `GetWindowsDirectory` or `GetSystemDirectory`, but I think they are deprecated.

Comment: They aren't deprecated and are the best when it comes to compatibility with older systems.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WinAPI function GetWindowsDirectory() to get the Windows folder, and GetSystemDirectory() to get the Windows\System folder. Thely're guaranteed to work with all Windows versions since at least Win95; I think they were available in Win 3.x as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with WinAPI, I'd use [SearchPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527(VS.85).aspx) e.g. the following will populate the variable `path` with the result.

```
//Get the full path to notepad
char path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
LPSTR* ptr = NULL;
DWORD dwRet = SearchPath(NULL, "notepad.exe", NULL, MAX_PATH, (LPSTR)path, ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a DOS prompt, change to the Windows folder and do:

```
dir notepad.exe /s
```

Long live DOS :)

Comment: technically correct, but brute-force & only works for stuff within the windows folder

Answer (score 0):

In short I find that the best approach
is to check the
`Windows\System32` directory
and the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` registry keys.

More generally I find that the best approach
is to mimic `ShellExecuteEx`.

Taken from:
Application Registration (Windows)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx

> The file is sought in the following locations:
>   •The current working directory.
>   •The Windows directory only (no subdirectories are searched).
>   •The Windows\System32 directory.
>   •Directories listed in the PATH environment variable.
>   •Recommended: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

A further possibly is to check `Start Menu\Programs\Accessories`,
by using `SHGetFolderPath` with `CSIDL_STARTMENU := 11`
and `CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU := 22`, and retrieve the targets
from the lnk files.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the system32 folder and type "notepad.exe" into the 'File Name' bar.