# How to find the directory of an exe that is on path

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there any simple way to get the full directory of an exe that the windows is mapping though the PATH environment variable?

Something like:

```
C:\>whereis myexe
```

Comment: What windows version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this answer. You could turn the script shown here into a batch file that would work as you have suggested in your question:

[Find the path of notepad.exe and mspaint.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519410/find-the-path-of-notepad-exe-and-mspaint-exe)

Also, the Where commmand in Windows 7 does this:

```
where myexe.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this batch file and give the exe file as argument

```
@setlocal
@set P2=.;%PATH%
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%~n1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$P2:i"=="" echo %%~$P2:i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the UNIX "which" command. Here's a windows version:

http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2004/11/equivalent_of_which_in_windows.html